# Choosing a location on MapKit and get latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I implemented to get the current location by `CoreLocation` & `CLLocation`.

In another UIViewController, I want to choose a location on `MapKit` and get latitude and longitude from `MapKit`. I searched a lot but I found a few courses using Objective-C.

Or is there any course in Swift?

```
class CustomLocationVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapKitC: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapKitC.delegate = self
    let gestureZ = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.revealRegionDetailsWithLongPressOnMap(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureZ)
}

@IBAction func revealRegionDetailsWithLongPressOnMap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.began { return }
    let touchLocation = sender.location(in: mapKitC)
    let locationCoordinate = mapKitC.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapKitC)
    print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")
}
```

}

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your `MKMapView` instead of your `ViewController.View`

Replace your `viewDidLoad` method by this one

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapKitC.delegate = self
    let gestureZ = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.revealRegionDetailsWithLongPressOnMap(sender:)))
    mapKitC.addGestureRecognizer(gestureZ)
}
```

After that your method should work as intended

Hope this helps